# How to add a new Task into the parent component array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm expecting to add a new task object and visualize it in the parent component array by clicking the Add button. But I'm havingg an error newTask is not defined. Even though I'm forming the newTasks in the child component and passing it to the parent array in the vuex.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-bootstrap-vue-dynamic-img-bkwixg?file=store%2Findex.js,components%2FTask.vue,pages%2Findex.vue

```js
// Child component

methods: {
    addTask() {
      let newTask = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
        title: this.title,
        completed: false,
      };
      if (newTask) {
        console.log(newTask);
        this.$store.dispatch('addTask', newTask);

        this.title = '';
      }
    },
  }
  
  // Store
  
  export const state = () => ({
  tasks: [],
});
  
  const actions: {
    async addTask(context, data) {
    data = {
      ...data,
      newTask,                        // getting an error here - newTask is not defined
 
    };
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'appication/json;charset=utf-8',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.dispatch('getTasks');
    }
    return res.ok;
  },
  }
  
  const mutations: {
    setTasks(state, data) {
    state.tasks = data;
    },
  }
```

store

Answer (score 0):

I checked your project and I found the error.

```
async addTask(context, data) {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'appication/json;charset=utf-8',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.dispatch('getTasks');
    }
    return res.ok;
},
```

When you call API, Backend doesn't add newTask, This is error.
So when you get response, there isn't newTask data that you added.

Comment: Thx, I would highly appreciate if you now how to fix it

Comment: Also please see the code at the top - there is actually a newTask prop I'm passing